# Запятая после "НО"

Tags: пунктуация

Ув. филологи! Подскажите, требуется ли запятая после "но" (для выделения обращения)?

Но папа, у тебя есть уже все эти инструменты!

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, здесь обычное обращение, которое отделяется от союза "но" запятой

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что союз НО здесь употребляется в значении частицы со значением возражения собеседнику и запятой от обращения не отделяется (но больше я так не думаю, см. дополнение)

Частицы часто встречаются перед обращением, они   придают ему эмоциональность, например:
О любимые сердцем обманы!  Ах витязь! То была Наина! Смерть, а смерть, ещё мне там дашь сказать одно словечко?

Обычно частицы следует отличать от междометий, для сравнения: О, память сердца! Ах, поля мои, борозды милые!  Эх, приятель, и ты, видно, горе видал, коли плачешь от песни весёлой. Эй, садись ко мне, дружок!

Проверить правильность решения можно по наличию паузы. В приведенном примере пауза после "НО", скорее всего, отсутствует.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ/ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ
Примеры из Нацкорпуса показывают, что запятую после союза НО надо ставить, хотя пауза там отсутствует (это грамматическая запятая). Таким образом, с помощью интонации мы различаем частицы и междометия (например, "ну, папа" и "ну папа"), но для слова НО, не составляющего пару частица/междометие интонационное решение не годится.

Примеры:

Почему ты вернулся сюда? ― Но, папа! Вы с матерью тоже не хотите никуда уезжать.

Но, папа, ты сам рассказывал, что Дзержинский за своей невестой через всю Европу поехал, когда первая мировая началась.

Ты мастер, у тебя верный глаз, но, папа, настоящий художник для меня что-то другое.

Я не буду платить этих денег! ― Но, папа, это долг чести.

Comment: А как отличить " О, память " от "о обманы "?

Comment: О обманы - эмоциональное обращение. О, память - междометие "О" выражает сильное чувство, а далее следует обращение. В устной речи варианты различаются по ударению и паузе. О обманы - нет паузы, интонационно выделяется обращение. О, память - пауза, два тонических ударения. Так что в этих случаях всё зависит от желания автора. А вот в приведенном примере вариант "но, папа" с паузой и ударение на "но" мне кажется не очень подходящим для обращения к папе.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен! Трудно в этом случае представить паузу после союза "но''. Тем более, что правила не регламентирует подобного обособления.

Вот только что пришло на ум - Евгений Онегин(Пушкин). Цитирую: <...> "но, ****боже мой,**** какая скука с больным сидеть и день и ночь!" Здесь, конечно, это не обращение. Но как быть, если та же самая фраза употребляется в качестве обращения?!

Да, конечно междометие! Я имею в виду, как быть, когда та же самая фраза выступает в качестве обращения. А вот еще пример: " Но, боже! как тяжко внимать Чужой нарастающей страсти!". Как Вы думаете, здесь разве не обращение? Примеры - отсюда: http://personal_names_of_russian_poets.academic.ru/292/%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%96%D0%95

Comment: Боже мой - это не обращение, а междометное выражение, которое всегда обособляется. Кстати, паузы здесь нет, запятая ставится по грамматическому принципу. НО - это союз. Вот также у Бунина: "Но, боже мой,что же было бы дальше"! Надо найти пример, где после противительного союза НО следует реальное обращение.

Comment: Серж, вы меня убедили своим примером, думаю, что запятую надо ставить (см. дополнение к ответу).

Comment: Разные есть варианты: "Неужто ж точно, боже мой, Я здесь любил, я здесь был молод" – это междометие, "Боже, боже, исполненный власти и сил, Неужели же всем ты так жить положил" – это обращение.